# java arraylist indexOutOfBonds Exception reason

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add various items in various positions in an arraylist. 
I need to use arraylist as the number of elements to be read is unclear.

while I am adding elements I am getting indexoutofbonds exception.
I understand that If the index is larger than size() I may get the exception.
but since I suppose that the size will be increased when I try to add more elements than size of the arraylist, why I am getting exception? difference between array and arraylist is that arraylist is dynamic and handle size issues? Am I wrong?

An example is as follows. I am using arraylist of arraylists.

```
arr.add(e1,new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

in that case e1 may be 1,0,10001,4,540,100000

Isn't arraylist should handle that problem?

What I mean is
I don't want to use that method below. I need spaces between the elements so that other elements can fit into their locations as the program reads the data. I don't want them to be shifted as the add method specified for the above code is taking a position and element. I don't want to add the item to next available position.

```
arr.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Any help will be useful. OR you can ask me to use another data structure in Java that will help my problem.

Comment: Where is the full code?  What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.I figured it out. ArrayList always shifts. You can not leave spaces between elements. That was what I was looking for.

Late answer better than never;)

Answer (score 2):

It'll take care of the dynamically for you if you *don't* specify the index you want to insert. But if you want to insert at a specific position, you must be sure that:

```
index >= 0 && index < size()
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-):

> Inserts the specified element at the *specified position* in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
>
> ..
>
> **Throws**:
>
> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)),

> public void add(int index,
>          E element)
>
> Throws:
>       IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

You must ensure that the index is not out of range.

In other word, if you specify index which `> size()`, `ArrayList` don't know how to manipulate the elements between `size()` and the index. Should it construct these elements and add them for you, maybe by default constructor? I think it should be your responsibility. Such as:

```
if (e1 > arr.size()) {
    arr.addAll(Collections.nCopies(e1 - arr.size(), Integer.valueOf(0)));
}
arr.add(e1, new ArrayList<Integer>());
```